# Recode NAs in multiple dataframe columns

Tags: r

I have multiple integer columns in a data frame, all with NAs that I need to recode to 0.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(paste(sample(letters,50,T),sample(letters,10), sep=""), function(x) {sample(c(NA,0:5),10,T)} ))
df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(paste(sample(letters,5,T),sample(letters,10,T), sep=""), function(x) {sample(letters[1:5],10,T)} ))
df <- cbind(df2,df1)
```

Producing an output like this... (only the first few columns of the 55 shown)

[image]

I can go about recoding the NAs to 0 manually like `df$col[is.na(df$col)] <- 0` for each column, but given that there are so many columns, it would take a while to type that all out.

**How can I recode all of these NAs to 0 in a line or three?**

(I realise I could melt the integer columns and then recode the one melted column, but I'd rather do this in base R)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were very close:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

Comment: Woah.... can't believe it was that easy. How could I then specify a range of columns to recode, instead of all of them?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. `df[6:10][is.na(df[6:10])] <- 0`. I didn't even think to add two square brackets in a row.

Comment: @TommyO'Dell, No problem. Like I said, you were very close!

Answer (score 2):

Using `plyr`'s `colwise` meta-function makes this easy:

```
dfZ=colwise(function(x)ifelse(is.na(x),0,x))(df)
```

Comment: although @mrdwab's method is certainly shorter to type.