# Replace NA with 0 in R using a loop on a dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to run through specific columns in a dataframe and replace all NAs with 0s using a loop.

```
extract = read.csv("2013-09 Data extract.csv")
extract$Premium1[is.na(extract$Premium1)] <- 0
extract$Premium1
```

gives me the required result for `Premium1` in dataframe `extract`, but I would like to loop through all 27 columns of premiums, so what I am trying is

```
extract = read.csv("2013-09 Data extract.csv")

for(i in 1:27) { 
  thispremium <- get(paste("extract$Premium", i, sep="")) 
  thispremium[is.na(thispremium)] <- 0
}
```

which gives

```
Error in get(paste("extract$Premium", i, sep = "")) : 
  object 'extract$Premium1' not found
```

Any idea on what is causing the error?

Comment: get() will not parse a string. Perhaps: `get("extract")[[paste0("Premium",i)]]` although it looks rather tortured. Why do you need to `get` 'extract'. Why not just: `extract[[paste0("Premium",i)]]`

Comment: Give a look at this answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311710/recode-nas-in-multiple-dataframe-columns)

Comment: Thank you for that observation, DWin. I am using `for(i in 1:27) { 
  extract[[paste0("Premium", i)]][is.na(extract[[paste0("Premium", i)]])] <-0 
}` now which gives the required result.

Comment: @user1886721 I do not want to replace all NAs in my dataframe; nevertheless an interesting read, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the loop because of other requirements? Because it works just fine without one:

```
extract[is.na(extract)] <- 0
```

If you want to do the replacement for some columns only, select those columns first, perform the replacement, and substitute the columns back into the original set:

```
first5 <- extract[, 1 : 5]
first5[is.na(first5)] <- 0
extract[, 1 : 5] <- first5
```

More generally loops can (and should) be almost avoided in R – especially when manipulating data frames). Often operations vectorise automatically (like above). When they don’t, functions of the `apply` family can be used.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. I have seen this solution elsewhere on the internet but in my case I wish to remove the NAs only from a selected set of columns.

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I take note of your solution. Is there a way to make the column references relative so that the script will be editing the correct columns when the layout of the underlying dataframe changes?

Comment: @Adriaan Yes, of course. In fact you *should* use variables instead of hard-coded absolute columns. Just substitute the (variable) names of the columns instead of the range I’ve used. For instance, use something like `c('Premium1', 'Premium3')` instead of `1:5`.

Comment: Wow, fantastic! What I am using now is `working <- extract[, c(paste0("Premium", 1:27))]
working[is.na(working)] <- 0
extract[, c(paste0("Premium", 1:27)) ] <- working` and it solves the problem perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Adriaan In that case, no need for the `c(…)` even. Just use `paste0("Premium", 1:27)` directly.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. The code also can be shortened to `extract[, paste0("Premium", 1:27)][is.na(extract[, paste0("Premium", 1:27)])] <- 0`.

Comment: @Adriaan True, but personally I dislike the repetition of the selector in this case, hence my temporary assignment.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. The shortened code may also be difficult for the next user to understand.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
for (colname in names(extract))
  extract[[colname]][is.na(extract[[colname]])] <- 0
```

(or even `extract[is.na(extract)] <- 0`)

Or, if you are not doing it to *all* the columns (I think I misread your question):

```
for(i in 1:27) { 
  colname <- paste0("Premium",i)
  extract[[colname]][is.na(extract[[colname]])] <- 0
}
```

Alternatively, you don't really need to know the number of such columns:

```
premium <- grep("^Premium[0-9]*$",names(extract))
extract[premium][is.na(extract[premium])] <- 0
```

Comment: Thanks sds; yes, I would like only to tamper with specific columns. Your and Dwin's solutions solve the problem but I found Konrad's solution more elegant :)

Comment: I get this error: `Warning message:
In grep(names(extract), "^Premium") :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. I am not sure what this solution is trying to achieve, but if it is to select all columns with "Premium" in the heading then I'm weary of implementing it because there are other columns (such as `ReasPremium1` for reinsurance) that I would like not to touch.

Comment: Sorry, fixed arg order. This [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) selects the columns which _start_ with "Premium" and then have digits.